# using jQuery to bind a deeply rooted child element of an iFrame

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, binding, element

I am trying to bind a click event to a deeply rooted child element of an iFrame and am not having any luck.  I managed to target the iFrame via the .on('load') event and have that.  I then traversed the DOM of the iFrame in the variable I set and found what I was looking for 9 children deep.  What is the best way to be able to bind to this as using the .find method comes back with a length of 0 meaning it is not finding it.

Here is the inheritance:

```
iFrame(root)
aspnetForm(form)
s4-workspace(div)
s4-bodyContainer(div)
contentRow(div)
contentBox(div)
DeltaPlaceHolderMain(div)
DialogTable(table)
cells(3) 
ct100_PlaceHolderMain_btnOK(input) <---button I want to bind to it's click event.
```

So basically its got a form and a bunch of divs as parents and then a table and its directly inside one of the cells of the table(index position 3).

This is on SharePoint 2013 online and is the AttachFile modal dialog.  I am attempting to bind to the click event of the OK button so I can do stuff once they click the button instead of having to wait for the result of the file upload which can be lengthy depending on the file size and internet speed.  I want to pop up a loading screen once they hit the button so they aren't just sitting there wondering what is going on because nothing is displayed after its clicked.
Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I have tried with no luck:

```
 SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options); //pops up the Attach File modal

 $('.ms-dlgFrame').on('load', function () { //waits for iFrame to load
      var iBody = $('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find("body"); //returns the iFrame object correctly
      var iContent = iBody.find('#ct100_PlaceHolderMain_btnOK'); //does NOT find this--length is 0
      console.log(iBody);
      console.log(iContent);
  });
```

UPDATE:
 Ok so I realized the button id is ctl like control not ct1...but it still doesnt work. I actually am grabbing the aspnetForm with iContent = iBody[0].children.perforM and am attempting to target the form's submit event which is what the OK button is...however I cant get that to work either with

```
iContent.submit(function() {
// do stuff
})
```

It just doesn't work. I also can grab the submit button itself by doing iContent = iBody[0].children.aspnetForm.ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$btnOK

However once again attempting to attach to the submit or click event doesn't work.

I'm at a loss here...I have the form and am targeting the submit event because when I console log it it says "form id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="blah blah""
Why isn't this working no matter what I am doing even when I have the right DOM element??

UPDATE 2:

Cannot get this working...

I bind to the iframe and find the aspnetForm and then have tried attaching to the submit and  onsubmit event, the ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_btnOK click event, etc.  These work but once the item submits I get a "Permission denied" even though it is coming from the same SharePoint site and should have the same domain.  It appears the button click happens and then the file uploads and the event doesn't try and fire until AFTER the modal closes, which I assume is being denied because there is no modal there.  When I put the call inside the .bind event, it fires again but then the length of the iFrame is 0 at that point meaning its no longer there.  I've even put it outside the bind call in an interval once it checks to see that frame has been loaded by use of a hasLoaded variable I set to true once the bind even fires, but then I get permission denied once the OK button is pressed with the only child element iContent has at this point being "error": "permission denied"

I know there HAS to be a way to do this and it's very frustrating Microsoft would leave this crappy functionality with no way of attaching a loading screen or even activation their OWN loading modal.  I can either activate the modal once the attach file modal pops up or once it closes but not in relation to when the 'OK' button is clicked to actually upload the file.  I know I can wait for the result to come back but that defeats the purpose because at that point the file is already uploaded.  I need a way to display a loading page in between the OK button(id: ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_btnOK) and the result coming back(ie, it appears when the OK button gets clicked and disappears once the dialogresult from the modal returns).  Any suggestions?  Nothing I have tried has worked so far. Using jQuery---either I get a permission denied error or the iFrame length is 0---its almost like the element doesn't allow event handlers on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution!

`$('.ms-dlgFrame').on('load', function() {
    $(this).contents.find('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_btnOk').on('click', function() {
        alert('clicked!');
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Give the button its own id and bind to that.

id="myButton"

Then in JQuery

```
$('#myButton').  etc
```

Comment: How can I give it an id when I can't find it in the first place?  It's already got an id on it...#ct100_PlaceHolderMain_btnOK

Comment: If it has an id and it is in the DOM, you should just be able to bind it directly using the id.

Comment: I know I should but I can't...it returns a length of 0 when I attempt to find it using it's ID.  I know it's there because I wait for the IFrame to load and the IFrame itself is there.  I have the following:                                   var iBody = $('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find("body");
var iContent = iBody.find('#ct100_PlaceHolderMain_btnOK');                                                            iBody returns the proper object but iContent returns with a length of 0

Comment: Why don't you put the code of what you have tried in the question, it may help people to solve the issue.

Comment: Is the HTML in the iframe from the same domain as the main HTML? If not, you may be coming up against the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: Yes I believe so, it's coming from the same SharePoint site